# awk IGNORECASE in for loop

Tags: awk

I know awk has IGNORECASE to make the operation case insensitive. But I am not able to figure out how to use it in a for loop.
For example: Consider this awk script:

```
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        counter[$i]++
}
```

Here I know I can use tolower, but what if I want to do it with IGNORECASE = 1, so that it ignores case while counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tolower seems the way to go. Look here for further info:

"In general, you cannot use IGNORECASE to make certain rules case-insensitive and other rules case-sensitive, because there is no straightforward way to set IGNORECASE just for the pattern of a particular rule.17 To do this, use either bracket expressions or tolower(). However, one thing you can do with IGNORECASE only is dynamically turn case-sensitivity on or off for all the rules at once."

from: The GNU Awk User's Guide

EDIT:

You should think about a better specification of your problem. Try this:

```
#Input: hello Hello HELLO World 
#Output: hello 3 World 1 

{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    a=tolower($i) 
    count[a]=$i","count[a]
    }
}

END{for (i in count){
    split(count[i],res,",")
    l=length(res) - 1 
    if (l==1){
        print res[1],1 
    } else {
        print tolower(res[1]),l}
    }
}
```

HTH Chris

Comment: Chris, the problem with tolower is that it converts everything to lowercase while printing the final output. What if I want it to maintain the case of other words while doing an output

Comment: How about: a=$i,counter[tolower(a)]++. This leaves $i untouched, but increases the counter case insensitive.

Comment: Chris, I have one more issue now. How do I output the word and count now: for (word in counter)
        printf "%s\t%d\n",word, counter[word]     This still does not maintain the case of the words when printing out

Comment: This is getting confusing and kind of a new problem. Please give us a example of your input and desired output. Then i can help you better.

Comment: input: hello Hello HELLO World                                        Output:                                                                   hello 3                                                                         World 1

Comment: currently it gives: hello 3 world 1                                         (Note the case of world is not maintained)

Comment: See my edited answer. If this still does not answer your problem, take a step back, think about a better description of your problem and open a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot chris, that finally solved my issue. Sorry to trouble you, is there any nice book or website to learn awk. I am interested in this scripting language. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Aho, The awk programming language is the best. But the gawk manual by robbins is very good and free.